# log4net log message does not contain method name

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net

I am trying to include the method name `%method` in log messages when using **log4net**. However, if I look at the log output it only shows a `?` where method name should be.

I know in reading the log4net docs that this is only available with `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` and this should only be used in development and not release builds.

Trying to make this work in a .NET Core application using the [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore)
 and the call to `.AddLog4Net();` in `Startup`

Here is the conversionPattern for the RollingFileAppender

```xml
<conversionPattern value="%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - MESSAGE: %message%newline %exception" />
```

I have put together a github repository with bare bone example of what I'm trying to get at. If you run the project you see the log file output does not contain method information.

Repository available at [log4net-netcore-example](https://github.com/scottluskcis/log4net-netcore-example)

In reviewing various SO articles, I've not found the solution to this yet. I'm assuming I'm missing a configuration or maybe a nuget package required to make this work.

Appreciate any insights anyone can provide.

Comment: Did you found answer for your question? I'm facing the same problem now, and I can't figured it out.